# Adding the time-cond flag to the python requests.get call?

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests, get

I am trying to add the --time-cond flag to a GET call using the python **request** package.  I want to check that the file is older than Jan 12 2022 for example before downloading.

I want to convert the *cURL* command:

```
curl -z "Jan 12, 2022" https://registry.verra.org/mymodule/ProjectDoc/Project_ViewFile.asp?FileID=11032&IDKEY=dkjalskjf098234kj28098sfkjlf098098kl32lasjdflkj909j15213128
```

[Note that in curl -z is short hand for --time-cond]

to something like this:

```
shapefile = requests.get('https://registry.verra.org/mymodule/ProjectDoc/Project_ViewFile.asp?FileID=11032&IDKEY=dkjalskjf098234kj28098sfkjlf098098kl32lasjdflkj909j15213128',
                         params = {`time-cond`:"Jan 12 2022"})
```

i.e. only fetching files modified since Jan the 12th

I am uncertain where in the docs this is mentioned.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/

---

What I tried...

```
shapefile = requests.get('https://registry.verra.org/mymodule/ProjectDoc/Project_ViewFile.asp?FileID=11032&IDKEY=dkjalskjf098234kj28098sfkjlf098098kl32lasjdflkj909j15213128',
params = {`time-cond`:"Jan 12 2022"})
```

There is no error, but changing the cut off date to wide values in the future and the past shows no change. Requests just seems to ignore the unrecognised parameters

Tried the params = {name:value} as I interpreted from the docs, in the first instance https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/

Comment: According to the [curl documentation](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-z) your command will get the file if it is *newer* than that date, not older. Which is normally what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"time-cond" is just the name of a CURL flag, it doesn't have any meaning in HTTP or the requests package.

To understand what it does you need to look at the request CURL generates. If you do, you'll find that it creates the `If-Modified-Since` or `If-Unmodified-Since` header. So to generate the equivalent request using the requests package you need to add the appropriate header.

You can do that with the [`headers` parameter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) (not `params`, which controls query parameters). Something like:

```
import datetime
requests.get(url, headers = {
        "If-Unmodified-Since": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12)
})
```